# CakePHP - sorting on deeply associated field

Tags: cakephp

I have the following associations:

`Invoiceitem` belongsTo `Invoice`
`Invoice` belongsTo `Supplier`

I want to retrieve `Invoiceitems`, subject to various conditions, but be able to sort on Supplier name.

So far I have:

```
$this->Invoiceitem->Invoice->belongsTo['Supplier']['order'] = "Supplier.name " . $direction;
$itemlist = $this->Invoiceitem->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'contain' => array('Invoice' => array('Supplier')),
));
```

This doesn't seem to work though - the results I get back appear to be sorted on Supplier name ascending, but if I try it with descending order, it doesn't make any difference.  I think the fact that the names are in order at all may just be a coincidence (I only have 3 of them, so they may just happen to be in order to start with).

Am I doing something wrong here?  How can I make it sort in descending order?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, cornelb... Am I supposed to highlight the Model names as code?  I'm not always sure what I'm doing on here!!

Comment: It isn't essential to format code snippets that are inline in a paragraph, but it does make them a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually resolved this by setting up a virtual field:

```
$this->Invoiceitem->virtualFields['supplierName'] = 
    'SELECT name FROM suppliers s JOIN invoices i ON s.id = i.supplier_id 
      WHERE i.id=Invoiceitem.invoice_id';
```

Seems to be working so far!

Answer (score 1):

I find deep operations don't work very well with containable, and so I often resort to manual joins.  But in this case you may be able to force it by doing something like the following, since if you make an option that CakePHP can't parse, it'll just default to inserting the unparsable part directly into your query.

```
$itemlist = $this->Invoiceitem->find('all', array(
     'conditions' => $conditions,
     'contain' => array('Invoice' => array('Supplier')),
     'order' => 'Supplier.name desc, Invoiceitem.id asc',
));
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm trying this out... will report back!!

Comment: This didn't work, I'm afraid... it said it didn't know the column Supplier.name.

Comment: Have taken a look at what mysql queries its generating?  IIRC, there are times where containable will actually do a find with contains through multiple queries, then join the data programmatically, which would explain why Supplier.name wasn't in your query.  The only solution then is to leave out the contains and do a join manually, so that all the joins will be done in one query, and you can sort by the associated columns.  See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables